# Is list a built in function or a class in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, list, class, class-method

```
>>> print(list(map(list,"abcde")))
[['a'],['b'],['c'],['d'],['e']]
```

Above is the most probable answer and correct as well however i thought of it in a bit different way.

Since map needs a function as the first parameter but list is a class right, so how map is working?

However i have heard of list as an inbuilt function as well which returns a list object. Only a class can return an object which is nothing but creation of an object. But if it is a class then list should have been written in camelcase according to the naming convention of classes in python which is not the case.

All the above points lead me to a conflict that list is a class or method in python?

Answer (score 4):

`list` is a built-in class in Python. However, classes are callable just like functions, and when called, classes instantiate and return objects, so you can pass a class as an argument where a function (or a callable to be precise) is expected.

Answer (score 1):

> Since map needs a function as the first parameter but list is a class right, so how map is working?

`map()` needs a *callable* as first parameter. You can [define custom callable types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-callable-objects) in Python, and Python classes are indeed callable objects.

> However i have heard of list as an inbuilt function as well which returns a list object.

Quite a few builtin types are indeed still documented as being functions (which they were in 1.x days if I recall correctly).

> Only a class can return an object

Oh yes ? This would mean that, since everything in Python is an object, functions cannot return anything - not even the `None` singleton object ;-)

> which is nothing but creation of an object. But if it is a class then list should have been written in camelcase according to the naming convention of classes in python which is not the case.

Same thing as above - quite a few builtin types are named as functions, mainly for historical reasons. And there are cases where it makes sense to not follow the naming conventions, even in your own code. As an example, decorators taking arguments can be defined either as doubly nested functions or as callable classes. If your module first defined a decorator as function, then for whatever reason (readability, testability, whatever) you decide to change the implementation to a callable class, you certainly don't want to break client code by renaming it in CamelCase.

Actually, the whole point of having the same mechanism to call functions or instanciate classes is to allow replacing one with the other without breaking client code - another application of OO's most important feature: polymorphic dispatch.

> All the above points lead me to a conflict that list is a class or method in python?

It's a class, definitly. You can just test it in your python shell:

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> type(list)
<class 'type'>
>>> type(dict)
<class 'type'>
>>> type(property)
<class 'type'>
>>> type(type)
<class 'type'>
>>> type(len)
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for such a deep explanation. However i am still a bit confused. From the discussion above i understood that map expects a callable not restricting it to only functions but an entire family if callables. According to my experience i have a perception that all classes are callables that is how they create objects right. So why is it not working with custom classes(Please refer to the code below). Can you explain me that as well, why is it throwing the error?

Code uploaded at github along with error: https://github.com/Git101pt/Callables.git