# finding all the indices of with a value in a list of lists

Tags: python, indices

I am trying to find all the indices that have the same values in a list.
but in my list, there are lists inside the list and I don't know how to do it
I found how to do that for a normal list:

```
list=[2,5,9,1,3,1]

list.index(1)
```

it will print the indices of value

`1: [3,5]`

but for this list:

```
list=[1, [2,3,17] , 3 , [0,1,2,7,3] , 2 ]
```

for the value `2`

it will need to print: `[[1, 0], [3, 2], [4]]`
but I don't know how to do that for this kind of list.

Comment: `lst.index(1)` will print 3, not [3, 5]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262994/find-index-of-element-in-sub-sub-list

Comment: This is your answer maybe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find index of element in sub-sub-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262994/find-index-of-element-in-sub-sub-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, don't name any variables `list` in python -- it is already a function.
To answer the question, you can loop through the list and use recursion each time there is a list inside of the list:

```py
def getNestedIdxs(l, num): # l is the list and num is what we are looking for
    result = []
    for idx, element in enumerate(l):
        if element == num: result.append([idx])
        elif isinstance(element, list): # This checks if the element is a list
            result.extend([[idx] + elem for elem in getNestedIdxs(element, num)])
    return result

print(getNestedIdxs([[[1, 2, 3,[0,1,2]], 2, [1, 3]], [1, 2, 3]], 2))
```

Comment: Well, *list* is NOT a defined keyword, but a *class*  or *function* - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61078558/